# Python append array to array in loop

Tags: python

I'm coming from PHP to python.

In PHP i do this:

```
$result = array();

foreach($videos as $video) {
  $result[] = array("title"=>$video->title,"description"=>$video->title);
}

print_r($result);
```

Now when i try this in python flask i get an error **We're sorry, but something went wrong: Web application could not be started**

```
result = {}

for video in videos:
    title = video['title']
    description = video['description']
    content = {'title':title, 'description': description}
    result[] = content
```

How do i solve?

Here is full function

```
@app.route("/add_channel", methods=['POST'])
def add_channel():
    if request.method == "POST":
        id=request.form['channel']
        videos = get_channel_videos(id)

         result = []
         for video in videos:
             result.append({'id': video['id'], 'title': video['snippet']['title']})
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

If your final result is a list of dictionaries, that last line would be

```
result.append(content)
```

More concisely that could be achieved in a list comprehension

```
result = [{'title': video['title'], 'description': video['description']} for video in videos]
```

Comment: tried `result.append(content)` and get this error **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'**

Comment: just change result = {} to result = [], result = {} declares a dictionary

Comment: You would use list initialization before the loop `result = []` otherwise `{}` creates a dictionary

Comment: Still get an error ** TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.**

Comment: I've tried all suggestions but still get an error when i return the result.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? You mentioned `flask` but what specific function are you calling that you are trying to pass `result` to?

Comment: @user892134 Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960188/flask-is-returning-typeerror-the-view-function-did-not-return-a-valid-response/56962069